# Ubuntu - The right permissions to use file_put_contents

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, permissions

In my PHP application I am using `file_put_contents()` to create a file to display comprising of a blob retrieved from a table in my database. However, currently, in order to get the function to work on my Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance, I had to give the folder it's writing to `777` permissions. However, I know this is extremely bad and I want to change this, but I don't know what to.

I'm a novice at Linux and I'm currently navigating around my instance through the help of Google. This is part of a university assignment, so I can't just hire a Linux expert (just in case one of you says I shouldn't be using such an instance if I don't know Linux!)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using this from a browser with normal http requests, you need to find out what the user is that is running the web-server. Probably something like `apache`, `www-user` or something similar.

Then you can do 2 things:

- Change the ownership of the directory where you want to save the file to the web-server user and then it can have permissions 755
- Change the group of the directory to the group of the web-server and then the directory needs 775.

Comment: I used `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/public`, is that suffice or do I need to find the web-server user? Because I'm not sure what is. I tried both `www-user` and `apache` along with `chown` command but SSH terminal says that neither user is recognised.

Comment: @RoyalSwish No, you need the web-server user otherwise it cannot write in that directory. You can try a `$ ps aux` on the command line to see what processes are running and the web-user should be obvious from the results.